# Spring: How to autowire or (use new) a bean with constructor parameter and which is not a managed bean

Tags: java, spring

There are many similar questions here but none showing how to do it. Here, how can I autowire CreateDatabaseAction bean and use it? It expects a Shoppingcart object, and it is NOT a spring managed bean. Or do I have to create it with new keyword?

```
public abstract class AbstractServiceActions {
  @Autowired
  protected DatabaseModel dbModel;

  protected User user;

  public AbstractServiceActions(ShopingCart cart) {
     this.user = user;
 }
```

And implement it:

```
@Component
 public class CreateDatabaseAction extends AbstractServiceActions {
      public CreateDatabaseAction(ShoppingCArt cart){
            super(cart);
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way for Spring to know what `ShoppingCart` instance to use when instantiating `CreateDatabaseAction` if there is no managed bean of that type. I think that you should reconsider the design. For example send it as method parameter where it's actually used and remove it from the constructor.

Considering only the names, I would say that `ShoppingCart` would be a good candidate for a session scoped bean.

Comment: thats actually not shopcart, a response i got from webservice, and I am handling webservice response

Comment: If it is a web service response and you do not need it at constructor level, why don't you set it on the bean after the bean is instantiated? My comment is assuming you have control over `AbstractServiceActions` class

Comment: @Dhanush Gopinath because the moment instantiete CreateDatabaseAction with a parameter I want it ready to be used immidiatly without setting a parameter than calling another method to run a business logic on it, I want eberything to be done and ready in construction initiliazation

Comment: @Dhanush Gopinath So developer dont need to open the abstract class and check what methods he needs to call to init the object

Comment: If you can modify the constructor I can suggest you an alternate solution. But otherwise you can't inject class which is not a Spring Bean

Comment: @ Dhanush Gopinath  I can modify everything yes

Comment: Adding too much business logic within the constructor is bad design and bad practice. You could also face race conditions because your object reference may "escape" while it is in an inconsistent state. If ShoppingCart is an external request (input) it cannot be a constructor parameter but a method parameter of you comonent CreateDatabaseAction

Comment: @medveshonok117  any problem with making it a method parameter in base class AbstractServiceActions?

Comment: Not a problem at all. You can have an abstract method on AbstractServiceActions and let the subclasses to implement it.
Remember also that ShoppingCart is an "external" mutable input (probably from a Http request I presume) so it cannot be a member field (as you did with the constructor): unless configured otherwise, Spring implements a Singleton pattern while it makes instances of its managed beans.